# Was the Old Prophet (1 Kings 13.18) deceived by an 'angel'?

Tags: angels, 1-kings, deception

Most translations read '(But he was lying to him)'. I always thought the Old Prophet lied to the man of God, but now I'm wondering if the 'angel' lied to the old prophet.

This wondering started when reading Systematic Theology, Wayne Grudem chapter 19 Angels pp. 406-407. 1 Kings 13.18 is used as an example of 'false doctrine or guidance being conveyed by angels ... the clear possibility of satanic deception tempting us to disobey ...'

Having investigated, some translations put 'the old prophet lied' which makes it clear (if they are correct??). Any gentle help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Oooor it could have just been the fact that this old prophet plainly lied about seeing an angel just to manipulate the man of God from Judah to disobey God and eat with him. Hospitality was a big thing in Middle Eastern times back then.

But, most importantly, it seems this was a test for the young prophet, not the old prophet, as the former was the focal point of the chapter's story.

Hope these resources help you as well:

- https://ebible.com/questions/3718-why-did-the-old-prophet-lie-to-the-man-of-god-causing-his-death
- https://www.gotquestions.org/man-of-God-lying-prophet.html
- [What should the man of God in 1 Kings 13 have done when faced with the old prophet's lie?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/39702/what-should-the-man-of-god-in-1-kings-13-have-done-when-faced-with-the-old-proph)

Comment: Appreciate your time.  The 'got questions' link is very definite but I'm not sure how that author knows...

Comment: True, that's why I included 2 other sources as well.

Comment: thanks all the links were thoughtfully provided

Comment: You're welcome, Tim. :D

Answer (score 0):

According to the [interlinear](https://biblehub.com/1_kings/13-18.htm), the original Hebrew text (as best we can reconstruct it) has "he lied," not "the old prophet lied."  So, there is no way to know for sure.  Sorry.

Comment: I'm not supposed to say thanks, but thanks